# How to fully display color on the text of the sub menus in the navigation bar of recipes?

Tags: html, css

My question here is when I hover over recipes and when I move forward to the sub menus how do I make the blue hover perfectly fit the sub headings. Like the color is not covering the text fully. And for a better understanding please do read and run my code if you like.

> I am using this in the CSS

```
nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

> Here is the link please do check it.

https://jsfiddle.net/harisfaisal/q68n7ro4/2/

Comment: I can't figure out what kind of text appearance do you want. Adding some images examples may help people have deeper understanding according to your problem.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could share your code or images of what you currently have done and what you expect for

Comment: Hey I have edited my question and provided the information you guys asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because   `nav li {width:20%}` in your code is affecting all `li` elements including submenu so the color covers only 20% in submenus. It can be fixed by adding `width:100%;` in your `nav li li {}` selector.

Note: your code has repeated selectors, it's better to merge them to improve readability.